# SQL - When & How to filter with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have two tables.. One is customers and the other is orders. Orders has a foreign key that joins to the customers table. How should I go about returning data from both tables:

1. Filtered on a field in the orders table and,
2. Filtered on a field in the customers table?

Is using `WHERE` to filter after the `JOIN` in my `SELECT` statement the correct way to go, or putting in an AND within the JOIN statement? And would I have to use one method for one of the above situations and the other for the other one?

For example,

```
SELECT customers.customer_type, orders.grant_date

FROM orders

JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id

WHERE orders.order_id = 3;
```

or

```
SELECT customers.customer_type, orders.grant_date

FROM orders

JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id

AND orders.order_id = 3;
```

I guess I can summarize my questions as:

a. Which table should I pair with my `FROM` statement? Should it be the one which has the foreign key i.e. orders? Or does it depend on the situation?

b. How should I filter the data? With a `WHERE` or an `AND` with the `JOIN`? And how is one different from the other i.e. when should I use one over the other in my two situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you do

```
FROM orders
JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
```

or

```
FROM customers 
JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
```

Which table you make the first table is up to you. Here I would make `orders` the first table, because it is orders along with their customer information you are showing in your results.

With an inner join it doesn't make a difference either, whether you put criteria in your `WHERE` clause or `ON` clause.

However, it looks strange to join `customers` on a condition on `orders`:

```
JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id AND orders.order_id = 3
```

This is not how an `ON` clause is supposed to work. So either:

```
FROM orders
JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
WHERE orders.order_id = 3
```

or

```
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
WHERE orders.order_id = 3
```

or

```
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id AND orders.order_id = 3
```

Many people prefer the last query over the second last, because you can easily convert the inner join into an outer join. So the general advice is: put criteria on the first table in `WHERE` and the criteria on other tables in `ON`. Make this a rule of thumb.

Comment: I guess because I want data from both orders AND customers filtered on one of them each time, I would make use of an INNER JOIN both times and so keep the above in mind as rule of thumb. Right? @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: Yes, I have added a remark that I would make it `FROM orders JOIN customers`, because your result rows are orders with their customer data. I don't know if you saw this. Sometimes it's not that easy to decide which table to make the first one, but then it doesn't really matter, so you'd just decide for the order you like best.

Comment: Two remarks: 1) Use aliases to enhance readability: `from orders o join customers c on c.customer_id = o.customer_id`. 2) If you only want data from one table, then you don't have to join of course, e.g. `select * from orders where customer_id in (select customer_id from customers where vip = true)`.

Answer (score 2):

I my experience with SQL, when using an inner join (aka. join ), order of tables after the FROM clause has never made a difference in results. Also, it has not made any difference if I used a 'where' clause or an  'and' clause after the join. But this behavior is limited ONLY and ONLY to Inner joins. If you are using left or right joins, the order as well as Where/And clauses make a lot of difference in the results returned.

I'd like to add that if you have a lot of nulls in your keys(which should never be the case), that might affect the result set in inner joins when switching between Where and And or changing the sequence of tables after from.